# Asp.Net Mvc Checkboxfor default value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

model

```
[DefaultValue(true)]
public bool IsActive { get; set; }
```

view

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive)
```

html output and that is my expected

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="Yayında alanı boş bırakılmamalıdır!" id="IsActive" name="IsActive" type="checkbox" value="true" class="valid">
```

but checkbox is not checked. I cant understand why? What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: The 'best practice" in this case, imho, would be to set the value in the controller.  ie `model.IsActive = true;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx)

> > A DefaultValueAttribute will not cause a member to be automatically initialized with the attribute's value. You must set the initial value in your code.

Comment: Thanks for trick. I solve it in getter block. `get{ return true;}`

Comment: Setting it in the getter would cause the value to always be true, just as the code says. You could never set the checkbox to false.