# how to set a check box as default?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm using asp.net MVC 5 i want to set a check box as default but I'm failing to achieve this, in a razor.

I tried even this link:

> [How do I set a checkbox in razor view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157293/how-do-i-set-a-checkbox-in-razor-view)

**Controller**

```
 Active = memberViewModel.active
```

**view**

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.active, new { @checked = "checked" })
```

**Viewmodel**

```
 public bool active { get; set; }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asp.Net Mvc Checkboxfor default value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903500/asp-net-mvc-checkboxfor-default-value)

Comment: Is `model.active` set to `true`?

Comment: @ChrFin then on my razor?

Answer (score 3):

Your binding to a property so the checkbox state is determined from the value of the property. In your controller, set the value of `active` to `true` (or set it in a parameterless constructor of the class), and then in the view

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.active)
```

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If the value of property `isactive` is set to `true` when you pass the model to the view, the checkbox **will** be checked. Are you even passing the model to the view?

Comment: yes i did set active to true my problem is that the checkbox is not checked on the view

Comment: Thats got nothing to do with it! You need to set the value either in a parameterless constructor - e.g. `public class MyModel { public MyModel() { active = true; } public bool active { get; set; } }` or set it's value in the controller before you pass the model to the view - e.g.`MyModel model = new MyModel(); model.active = true; return View(model);`

Comment: And from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) _A DefaultValueAttribute will **not** cause a member to be automatically initialized with the attribute's value. You **must** set the initial value in your code._